# Don't allow duplicate email address to be inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql

This file for entering the mail

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
session_start();
$email = $_POST["EMAIL"];
$query = "INSERT INTO `newsletter` ( `EMAIL`)
 VALUES ( '$email')";
mysqli_query($link,$query);
echo mysqli_error($link);
$current = $_SESSION["current_page"] ;
header("location:../$current");
?>
```

and this File To Show the newsletter emails

```
?php
    include("php/connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";
    $result  = $link->query($query);
    while($array = $result->fetch_array() ){
        $id = $array["ID"];
        $email = $array["EMAIL"];



      echo "<tr>
                    <td>$id</td>
                <td>$email</td>



        </tr>";
    }
?>
```

If I insert the same email address several times it will insert it every time. 
Is there any way I can make no duplicate for same mail (if anyone enters the same mail have a massage that mean you are already subscribed)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT Distinct * From
```

or make your column unique.

The First returns only uni Rows in your table.

the last would guarantee that you only add unique email addresses in your table

more to distonct https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score -1):

MySQL will

```
INSERT INTO newsletter (EMAIL) 
SELECT EMAIL FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL FROM newsletter 
      WHERE EMAIL = '$email' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: here a a lot of threads where this won't function every time. Setting the uniqueness in the table, will guarantee it